# Gradient color changes with the height of the content view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have made a custom cell in its content view I have set its background with gradient effect.Below are my codes

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    view1.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    view1.layer.shadowRadius = 10
    view1.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0)
    view1.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    view1.clipsToBounds = false
    self.view1.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3;

    view1.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    view2.layer.cornerRadius = 5

    descriptionLabel.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    self.setupGradient()
}

func setupGradient() {
    let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
     gradient.frame = self.view2.bounds
     gradient.colors = [  UIColor(red: 152.0/255.0, green: 116.0/255.0, blue: 189.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor, UIColor(red: 105.0/255.0, green: 88.0/255.0, blue: 158.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor  ]
     gradient.locations = [0.0, 0.75]
     gradient.cornerRadius = 5
     self.view2.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, atIndex: 0)
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("RewardDetailCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! RewardDetailCell
     cell.descriptionLabel.text = labelArray[indexPath.row]
     cell.points.text = dataArray[indexPath.row]
     cell.totalPoints.text = pointsDetail[indexPath.row]
     return cell
}
```

As its height increases the gradient effect also changes absurdly.
[image]

Comment: add `cellforrowAtIndexPath` code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just override l**ayoutSubviews** method and make the gradient layer's frame equal to the related view's bound so that your gradient layer can have the same as the related view.

Comment: will you please show what you have written in this method.

Comment: also don't forget to call layoutIfNeeded for cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: I simply call the setupGradient()  method in layoutSubviews

Comment: You are doing wrong man, that's why it is not working. Another issue with your setupGradient() method is that it will add a new gradient layer to the view every time it will be called, which is totally wrong.

Comment: Make an instance variable for your gradient layer. Then add it to your view in awakeFormNib. Then update its frame in layoutSubviews.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have written in "setupGradient()" , call that method from cellForRowAtIndexPath , as awakeFromNib() will be called when the cell is created for first time so the rect for gradient layer is only for first cell and so it's height is not increased for other cell . so remove the line self.setupGradient() from awakeFromNib().  So you need to implement below code.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("RewardDetailCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! RewardDetailCell
    cell.descriptionLabel.text = labelArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.points.text = dataArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.totalPoints.text = pointsDetail[indexPath.row]
    cell.setupGradient()
    return cell
}
```